# why does "rm" command override the display of bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a simple bash script that finds specific files, then I sort and remove them. 
Here s the script :

```
find . -type -name "~*" | sort -n | head -5 | xargs rm
```

Is it possible to somehow first print results before I remove them?

Comment: What is your output? Plus, `~*` isn't a directory. Furthermore, this looks very dangerous as it could delete files you don't want it to, so I would advise you think carefully before running this.

Comment: You could also run ***xargs rm -v*** in order to have the rm command print what it deletes.

Comment: @bluerojo needed this! thank you. Haven't thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tee` is a possible solution, it's a part of `coreutils` so you should have it already installed on your system:

```
$ find .  -name '~*' | sort -n | head -5 | tee /dev/tty | xargs rm
```

BTW I believe you have an error in your `find` command - you have to pass a value to `-type` option.

Comment: Yes, the -type was just a type error, your code works like a charm thank you!